# Append string with variable

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, nsstring, nsmutablestring

I'm a java guy coming over to Objective-C. In java, to add a variable to a string you'd have to do something along the lines of:

```
someString = "This string is equal to " + someNumber + ".";
```

I can't figure out how to do it in Objective-C though. I have an `NSMutableString` that I'd like to add to the middle of a string. How do I go about doing this?

I've tried:

```
NSString *someText = @"Lorem ipsum " + someMutableString;
NSString *someText = @"Lorem ipsum " + [someMutableString stringForm];
```

and a few other things, none of which seem to work. Also interchanged the `+`s with `,`s.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use `appendString:`, but in general, I prefer:

```
NSString *someText = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Lorem ipsum %@", someMutableString];
NSString *someString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"This is string is equal to %d.", someInt];
NSString *someOtherString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"This is string is equal to %@.", someNSNumber];
```

or, alternatively:

```
NSString *someOtherString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"This is string is equal to %d.", [someNSNumber intValue]];
```

etc...

These strings are autoreleased, so take care not to lose their value. If necessary, retain or copy them and release them yourself later.

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
NSMutableString * string1 = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@"this is my string"];

[string1 appendString:@" with more strings attached"];

//release when done
[string1 release];
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to use `stringByAppendingString`

```
NSString* string = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"some string"];
string = [string stringByAppendingString:@" Sweet!"];
```

Don't forget to `[string release];` when your done of course.

Comment: Your memory management is messed up. It's the original string created by `alloc` that you need to release, but you're throwing that away (leaking it) and replacing it with the result of `stringByAppendingString:`, which should not be released.

Comment: I realize that I may be confused by memory management here, but isn't my 2nd statement pointing to the same block of memory, in which I am just reassigning the value to the existing value plus the appended string?

Comment: Nope, it's two different different objects at two different memory locations. Plain NSStrings can't change their value, so `stringByAppendingString:` returns a new string with the original string's value plus the appended value.

Comment: Since ARC this would not be a problem anymore?

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableString *string = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

[string appendFormat:@"more text %@", object ];
```