# Expression Result Unused (with array description)

Tags: objective-c, arrays, nsarray

Basically, I'm trying to print out an `NSArray's` description.

I'm getting `'Expression Result Unused'`, even though I've tried everything I could find online!

Does anyone know?

```
 NSArray *WalletBalance= [responseDict objectForKey:@"balance"];

 NSString *wBalance = (@"This wallet currently has %@ dollars", [WalletBalance description]);
```

How could I append `WalletBalance's` description into a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use:

```
NSString *someText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"This wallet currently has %@ dollars", [WalletBalance description]];
```

Courtesy of [Append string with variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7070046/append-string-with-variable)